# undefined custom icon react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add my own icons into a navigation bar(type react-navigation). When I return the IconComponent i get

```
undefined is not a function (near '..._reactNative.default.createElement...')
```

I've tried using Ionicons own icons but I get the same error. I've thought about if IconComponent requires some other input but I haven't found anything useful. 
How i'm implementing at the moment:

```
import React from 'react-native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import ListView from '../views/ListView';
import SettingsView from '../views/SettingsView'
import NearbyView from '../views/NearbyView'
import list from '../assets/icons/list.png'
import nearby from '../assets/icons/nearby.png'
import settings from '../assets/icons/settings.png'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    List: { screen: ListView },
    Nearby: { screen: NearbyView },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsView },
  }, { 
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
              const routeName = navigation.state
              let IconComponent = Ionicons;
              let iconName;
              if(routeName === 'List') {
                iconName = list;
              }
              else if(routeName === 'Nearby') {
                iconName = nearby;
              }
              else if(routeName === 'Settings') {
                iconName = settings;
              }

              return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
          }
      }),
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      },
  });

  export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably need to fix your imports. The path is not valid.

proper import route:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that made a difference. It works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your routeName

you wrote 
`const routeName = navigation.state`

instead of

`const { routeName } = navigation.state`

You also need to correct your imports

```
import React from 'react'
```

and in class delaration

```
export default class className extends React.Component{}
```